# Benefits over using object method over property from $product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, oop

I'm grabbing products from `wc_get_products()` and looping through them to display information in a foreach. Are there any benefits (performance or otherwise) to using `$product->get_name()` over `$product->name` or vice versa?

It appears you can pass a context variable into most of these get methods, so that seems like one benefit, but are there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *always* use methods over accessing properties directly, when they're available.

Methods are the 'API' for the object, and by using them you don't need to worry about the internal structure of the object's data, and it theoretically allows the object to be designed so that its internal structure can change without affecting code that consumes it. In a lot of code the properties are actually made impossible to access *without* a method. For backwards compatibility WooCommerce hasn't done this, and likely won't change the data structure for the same reason reason, but its best practice and you should get in the habit of using the methods.

In WooCommerce specifically, it also ensures that the value is passed through the `woocommerce_product_get_name` filter, which means that the value will properly reflect any modifications made by other plugins the user might be running. For example, the user might be running a plugin that uses the `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter to convert the price to an appropriate value for another currency. If your code uses `$product->price` instead of `$product->get_price()` then you'll be using the incorrect value in that context.